# How to prevent talkback to announce "double tap to activate" after every item in focus android?

Tags: android

In android talkback announce content descriptions followed by element type and after a few second announces - double tap to activate.
how to prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a user, you can turn off these hints in Talkback settings on the device:

> Accessibility -> Talkback -> Settings -> Verbosity -> Speak usage hints

As a developer, you should **not** remove these, as users need them to understand the app. Clickable views should have them by default, users have ability to remove them via settings if they wish. However, if you are getting these announcements on views which are not clickable, that's something that can be reviewed, are you using clickable views which don't have actual actions attached to them? Are decorative items announced when they shouldn't be?